# Laravel 5: class 'Illuminate\Database\Seeder' not found

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-seeding

Problem I'm currently facing to has been posted here already, yet none of them could solve my one.

I'm talking about database seeder located under url like `http://HOSTNAME/laravelfiles/database/seeds/UsersTableSeeder.php`. Its content is as follows:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // What should be being done, it is being done here :)
    }
}
```

Having opened this file directly (by url given above the code), following error is printed:

`Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Database\Seeder' not found in /var/www/laravelfiles/database/seeds/UsersTableSeeder.php on line 6`

I found possible solution. Doesn't work for me:

- `composer dump-autoload`

---

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
}
```

**NOTE:**  Even the code above produces the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You must run seeder class via command line, not browser.
you should open your command line and change directory to laravel root folder.
then you need to run command:

```
php artisan db:seed
```

and check your database.

for more info please check laravel documentation([Laravel Database Seeding](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/seeding))

Comment: I did it at first and because of it hadn't worked, I'm diagnosing it via browser.